# Example of set in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ that is compact but not $C$-compact

Tags: general-topology, convex-analysis, compactness

A set $Y \subset \mathbb{R}^{p}$ is said to be $C$-compact with respect to a cone $C \subset \mathbb{R}^{p}$, if for all $y \in Y$, then $(y-\text{cl }C)\cap Y$ is compact.

For $p = 2$, can anyone see a set $Y$ that is compact but not $C$-compact? I do not have an intuitive sense for how this is possible to destroy the strong conditions of compactness in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$!

Edit: A cone $C \subset \mathbb{R}^{p}$ is a set such that $x \in C \implies \alpha x \in C$ for all $\alpha \geq 0$.

Also,  $(y-\text{cl }C)\cap Y$ is equivalent to $(Y + (-\text{cl }C))\cap Y$.

Comment: What about $p=1$?  Can you get an example there?

Comment: Can you define a cone?

Comment: Also, can you confirm what $y-cl (C)$ means?  I assume this is setwise subtraction so $y-cl(C) = \{x  \in \mathbb{R}^p: x = y -b \mbox{ for some $b \in cl(C)$}\}$?

Comment: Addendum made to original post.

Comment: At first glance, since $y-\overline C$ is closed, and closed sets intersected w  compact sets are compact, how could there be such a set?

Comment: @zhw That has been my thinking, but some colleagues think there is a case otherwise!

Comment: The last line of your recent edit looks wrong: you are saying that something dependent on a point $y$ is equivalent to something that does not depend on that point.

Answer (score 1):

$y - \mbox{cl}(C)$ is the image of the closed set $\mbox{cl}(C)$ under the isometry $x \mapsto y - x$ and hence is closed. So if $Y$ is compact $(y - \mbox{cl}(C)) \cap Y$ is a closed subset of the compact set $Y$ and hence is compact. So compact sets are $C$-compact.

Comment: it's not a translate of that set.

Comment: @zhw: thanks for the correction.